# karma html reporter not working as expected

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, livereload

I am working on a MEAN stack app using karma-jasmine as unit testing framework I am trying to find a good html reporter for unit testing results

first I tried [karma-jasmine-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) but it not live reload the debug page I had to refresh it maually and this cause me stuck many times and thought the issue is in my code till I remember I have to reload the page!

I found this one also [karma-jasmine-html-reporter-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter-livereload) but it not working at all the debug page is blank and an error in the console

> jasmineRequire is not defined

Finally I tried this one [karma-html-live-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-html-live-reporter) the debug page is empty but with no errors in console and I can see the result of the tests logged in the console

**EDIT:** 
I found a solution with this one when I read the log carefully I found that live html reporter is not working on debug page as expected but on localhost:5060 !! which is very strange
but when I go there I found everything working perfect

how to configure karma to open this port automatically?

**package.json**:

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
"karma": "^1.6.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter-livereload": "^1.0.0",
```

please anyone has a similar situtaion could help or suggest something!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No version or config mentioned. [mcve]

Comment: question updated